# Solution of differential equation without laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following differential equation where $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$

$$y''+y=e^{-t^2}$$

Given that the laplace of $e^{-t^2}$ exists but without finding it, what is the solution to the differential equation?

Not sure how to solve this without using Laplace explicitly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you solve the associated homogeneous equation
$$y''+y=0$$
whose solution is a 2 dimensional vector space with a base given by $\{\cos(t),\sin(t)\}$. That is, its general solution is given by $y(t)=C_1 \cos(t)+C_2\sin(t)$. (This is related to the characteristic equation $\lambda^2+1=0$ having roots $a\pm i b$ with $a=0$ and $b=1$; in the general case you would have that $e^{at}\cos(bt)$ and $e^{at}\sin(bt)$ are two linearly independent solutions.)

Then you have to find one solution $y^*(t)$ of the complete (non homogeneous) equation, and so its general solution will be
$$y(t)=C_1 \cos(t)+C_2\sin(t)+y^*(t).$$

To find $y^*$, if no obvious function or type of function is evident, we can find one of the form
$$y^*(t)=A(t)\cos(t)+B(t)\sin(t),$$
as guaranteed by the method of variation of parameters. This one also states that $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ satisfy
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos(t) & \sin(t)\\
-\sin(t) & \cos(t)\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
A'(t)\\
B'(t)\\
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
e^{-t^2}\\
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Solving the system of equations, and integrating you can find one such $A$, one such $B$ and one such $y^*$, so then you'll have the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, the homogeneous part is solved by $y_{H}(t)=a \cos t + b \sin t$. We can use variation of parameters to determine the particular solution. You will have to evaluate integrals of the form $\int \cos(t)  e^{-t^{2}} dt$ and $\int \sin(t) e^{-t^{2}} dt$